# MediatR Logging Pipeline: Logs Not Triggering for Request Lifecycle

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, mediatr

I'm facing an issue with logging in my ASP.NET Core API application when using [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) for handling requests. Specifically, I have a custom logging pipeline behavior that is intended to log the start and completion of requests. However, it seems that the logging statements within the `LoggingPipelineBehavior` are not being executed.

Here's a simplified version of my `LoggingPipelineBehavior`:

```
public class LoggingPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
    where TResponse : ServiceCommandResponse<object>
{
    private readonly ILogger<LoggingPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>> _logger;

    public LoggingPipelineBehavior(ILogger<LoggingPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Starting request {@RequestName} {@DateTimeUtc}", typeof(TRequest).Name, DateTime.UtcNow);
        var result = await next();
        if (!result.Success)
        {
            var errorValues = result.Errors.Values;
            var errorKeys = result.Errors.Keys;

            _logger.LogInformation("Request falier {@RequestName} {@Error} {@DateTimeUtc}", typeof(TRequest).Name, errorValues, DateTime.UtcNow);
        }
        _logger.LogInformation("Completed request {@RequestName} {@DateTimeUtc}", typeof(TRequest).Name, DateTime.UtcNow);

        return result;
    }
}
```

And here's a simplified version of my `ServiceCommandResponse`:

```
public class ServiceCommandResponse<T>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> Errors { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
}
```

Additionally, here's a snippet of an API endpoint (`GetAsync`) where I'm using `_mediator`:

```
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(ServiceCommandResponse<IEnumerable<UserDto>>))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
[HttpGet(ApiRoutes.User.Get)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync()
{
    try
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Attempting to get all users");
        ServiceCommandResponse<IEnumerable<UserDto>>? result = await _mediator.Send(new GetQuery());
        _logger.LogInformation("Successfully retrieved all users");
        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Error while attempting to get all users");
        _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Also here is the logging level in appsettings:

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  }
```

I'm using `MediatR Version="12.2.0"`

Despite adding this behavior to MediatR and ensuring all necessary configurations, the expected logs for request initiation are conspicuously absent.

I've already checked:

- The logging middleware is [configured in Startup.cs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMNy0.png)
- The logging middleware precedes MediatR in the request pipeline.
- MediatR is correctly set up in Startup.cs.
- Dependencies for logging and MediatR are resolved.

Could someone lend their expertise to help me figure out why the logging statements inside LoggingPipelineBehavior might not be firing? Any insights, troubleshooting tips, or common gotchas to look out for would be greatly appreciated.

I'm eager to hear your thoughts! Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: What MediatR version are you using ? your code works perfectly with `MediatR` version 12 and `ASP.NET Core 7.0`. Additionally what is the logging level in appsettings ?

Comment: I'm using this `<PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="12.2.0" />` and this is the loging level:  `"Default": "Information", "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"`

Comment: IIRC changing generic constraints did the trick when I faced a similar problem: https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Migration-Guide-11.x-to-12.0#rolling-back-generic-constraints

Comment: did you inject `LoggingPipelineBehavior` properly?

Comment: Are you using any 3rd part loggers like NLog or Serilog?

Comment: @ChristianHeld with `where TRequest : notnull` worked. But in this way I can not have the controll of `var result`

Comment: @SatishYadav Yes I'm using Serilog